# Calculated Column In Hibernate In same Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have as entity class Student in that I have `roll_no`, `student_name`, `marks` columns My Entity Class below:

```
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "student")
    public class Student{

    @Id 
    private int roll_no;
    private String student_name;
    private int marks; 

    public int getRoll_no() {
            return roll_no;
        }

        public void setRoll_no(int levelid) {
            this.roll_no = roll_no;
        }

public String getStudent_name() {
        return student_name;
    }

    public void setStudent_name(String student_name) {
        this.student_name = student_name;
    }


public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks= marks;
    }

    }
```

I want to execute A NamedQuery Like :

```
select *, (case when marks > 35  then 'Pass' else 'Fail' end)  as final_result from student
```

How can I add calculated new column `final_result` in my entity class.
I don't want to add it in my actual table in DB
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bother the DB, make a getter:

```
public String getFinalResult() {
    return this.marks > 35 ? "Pass" : "Fail";
}
```

EDIT:

If you need finalResult to be an field for the json parser than try the following:

```
@Transient
@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
private String finalResult;

private int marks;

public void setMarks(int marks) {
    this.marks = marks;
    setFinalResult();
}

private String getFinalResult() {
    return this.finalResult;
}

@PostLoad
private void setFinalResult() {
    this.finalResult = this.marks > 35 ? "Pass" : "Fail";
}
```

The `@Transient` annotation prevent the field from persisting and `@PostLoad` ensures the field is set after the Entity is loaded from jpa.

Comment: I Tried with the above code but in my Out put I am not able to get the new calculated value My Hibernate Code is : `Query GetStudent= session_hiber.getNamedNativeQuery("Student.RollNo");
            
            query.setInt(0, 101);
            
            List<Student> student_row = (List<Student>) GetStudent.list();`
`session_hiber` is `sessionFactory`

Comment: @ansh What is the actual problem? Is the student_row empty? If you call getFinalResult() you will get a result unless the Student is null.

Comment: Yes, I am grtting the result but In that I am getting only `roll_no`, `student_name` and `marks` not the calculated column which is `final_result` I am generating response in the json format.:-  `{
      "roll_no": 101,
      "student_name": "Jhon S",
      "marks": 67
      }`

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above code but still I am not getting the `final_result` in my json responce.

Comment: is there any Maven dependency for `@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY) `

Comment: @ansh It is from com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty. Which parser do you use?

Comment: @ansh Which json parser did you use and can you post the method that parses the object.

Comment: Hi Tom, Please check my Hibernate code :
`session.beginTransaction();

stdObj.setRoll_no(101);

Example example = Example.create(stdObj);
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class).add(example);
List<Student> result_list = (List<Student>) criteria.list();

  return result_list;`

I am sending result_list to client and Client Side I am doing Parsing In Javascript.

Comment: @ansh Edit your answer to post code. Debug your code and look if the student in the result list has the desired field.

Comment: Hi Tom , I tried to debug by code and found control is not going to `setFinalResult()` my `@PostLoad` annotation not working.
I am using a `SessionFactory` based configuration, is it because of that??

Comment: @ansh Yes that is the case. You need to use interceptors or event: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html